# how can i force a linebreak in a txt database?

Tags: php, flat-file

I'm working with PHP, and I would like to create a line-break in my .txt database after every input.
Is this even possible and how? 
Please help, I have tried `/n` and `<br>` but these won't work.
Some code:

```
fwrite($handle,$artikelnummer);
fwrite($handle,$newData);
```

Between these two I want a linebreak

Comment: Can you share some code? The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by "txt database"? Is this a text field in an RDBMS table (like MySQL or Oracle) or are you storing data in a flat-file text file?

Comment: im storing data in a flat txt file

Comment: Just add "\n". ie fwrite($handle,$artikelnummer . "\n");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
fwrite($handle, $artikelnummer);
fwrite($handle, "\n");
fwrite($handle, $newData);
```

As Shikhar Bhardwaj pointed out, you could use PHP_EOL, instead of "\n", if you want to be completely OS platform independent...

**UPDATE:**
If what you expect is one *empty* line between lines, you have to write *2* newlines...:

```
fwrite($handle, $artikelnummer);
fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
fwrite($handle, $newData);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work for me"? What do you expect and what else do you get? However, see my updated answer for a possible explanation... :-)

Comment: Choose this as the correct answer, if this saved your ass :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
fwrite($file, $yourData . "\n");
```

Don't use `'\n'` as PHP will not recognize the escape sequence then.

If you want to be platform independent use  `PHP_EOL` which outputs `\r\n` or `\n` depending on the OS. Its a predefined constant. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

If you want an empty line after writing a line :

```
fwrite($file, $yourData . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Choose this as the correct answer if this answered your question!

Comment: done it ,, im new to stackoverflow but great answer to my question, im just a beginning programmer

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Backslash and letter n in double-quotes:

`fwrite($handle, "This is my text with \n a linebreak");`